# Content page, page numbers and few images missing after converting from LaTeX to HTML using htlatex

Tags: graphics, conversion, html, tex4ht

I am trying to make a User Manual in both PDF and HTML format. I have generated the HTML file using `htlatex` but my content page, page numbers and few of my images are missing from it. My images are all in JPG format. This is my main `.tex` file:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}  
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \makeatletter
        \@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{%
          \usepackage[dvips]{color,graphicx}
          \usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}
        }{%
          \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
          \usepackage{hyperref}

          \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}

          \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark} 
          \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=0.43in]{Images/Fugrologo.eps}} % right with logo 
    \fancyfoot{}%to remove centered default footer 
          \fancyfoot[L]{Fugro Roadware Inc.} 
          \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage \  of \pageref*{LastPage}}% page# of reference page(last)

          \fancypagestyle{plain}% no header, footer contains page number centered { 
          \fancyhf{} %for the pages outside of content, list of figures etc. 
          \fancyhead[R]{ \includegraphics[height=0.43in]{Images/Fugrologo.eps}} % right with logo

          \fancyfoot[L]{Fugro Roadware Inc.} \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage \  of \pageref*{LastPage}} 

          \pagestyle{fancy}
          \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
          \usepackage{fullpage}
        }
        \makeatother  

        \usepackage{epstopdf}  
        \usepackage{lastpage}  
        \usepackage{makeidx}  
        \usepackage[english]{babel}  
        \usepackage{float}  
        \usepackage{subfig}  
        \usepackage{multirow}  
        \usepackage{appendix} 
        \usepackage{verbatim} 

            \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix: Algorithm Parameters} \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix-Algorithm Parameters}

            \setlength{\topmargin}{-1.3cm} \setlength{\headsep}{0.6cm}

            \renewcommand{\tablename}{\bfseries{Table}}

            %The top margin above a chapter can be changed using the titlesec package 

        \hypersetup{
                bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
                unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
                pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
                pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
                pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
                pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
                pdftitle={My title},    % title
                pdfauthor={Author},     % author
                pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
                pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
                pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
                pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
                pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
                colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
                linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links
                citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
                filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
                urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links }
            }
            \input{Macro} %\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{{\underline{#1}}}

            \makeindex

            \renewcommand{\headheight}{0.6in} %Space above header \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} %thickness of line under header \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} %thickness of line on title page

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 

\input {bhg fgfgf sadasd}

\appendix 
\appendixpage 
\addappheadtotoc 
\printindex
\clearpage 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does any one know how to use the t4ht package along with the tex4ht? I think that might solve the problem.

Comment: As it stands, this is not really a MWE: there are lots of packages loaded that seem unlikely to be needed, and at least one `\input` of a file we don't have. As such, I'm closing as unclear: edit to fix this.